# Windows file API compatibility win 7 vs win XP

Tags: windows, winapi

I am using some file functions like createFile, readFile in windows.h and I am developing under windows 7. Should I worry about windows XP users of my program? They have a different version of kernel32.dll, right?

Comment: Those functions have been around for a LONG LONG time and will work just fine in earlier Windows versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find MSDN a very useful resource. Not only does it show you what arguments a function takes, what it returns and what it does, but it will also show you which versions of the operating system support that function. For example, the page for [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) has the following information listed under the **Requirements** section:

> **Minimum supported client**:    Windows XP [desktop apps only]
>
> **Minimum supported server**:    Windows Server 2003 [desktop apps only]
>
> **Header**:
>
> ```
> FileAPI.h (include Windows.h);
> WinBase.h on Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, 
>              Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP (include Windows.h)
> ```
>
> **Library**:
>
> ```
> Kernel32.lib
> ```
>
> **DLL**:
>
> ```
> Kernel32.dll
> ```

What this information tells you is that the function `CreateFile` is available on Windows XP and subsequent versions of Windows, that you must include `<windows.h>` to get the function, and that the function is exported via `kernel32.dll`.

Comment: And the only reason the docs say Windows XP is the earliest available, is that version is (currently) the oldest officially supported by Microsoft. The `CreateFile` function goes back to at least the very first Windows NT 3.1 from 1993.

Comment: @GregHewgill Right, thanks for clearing that up. I should have made a note of that in my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, have a look at your stdafx.h (precompiled header).  It should advise on what macros to set for targeting a base windows version.  Something like this:

```
// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.
```